# .find() is not a function it is returning like that when i'm trying to find a id from JSON file

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm trying to create a server in node using **expressjs**

When I'm trying to get a particular id from products.json and I'm trying find method in it but it is encountering me with an error saying **products.find is not a function**

```js
import express from "express";
import fs from 'fs'
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

const app = express()
const products = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('products.json'))

app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
    res.json(products)
})
app.get('/products/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = parseInt(req.params.id)
    const product = products.find(p => p.id === id)
    res.json(product)
})
```

product.json below here

```js
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "iPhone 9",
        },...
```

Comment: Well `products` is not an array, so it does not have a `find` method. Log it (or visit your */products* endpoint) to see the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1):

From the parsed JSON, `products` is an object like so:

```js
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "iPhone 9",
        }, 
        •••
    ]

}
```

If you want the array value to key `products`, consider [object de-structuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#syntax) here:

```js
const { products } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('products.json'))
```